# Consulta para filtrar duplicados no funciona

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

Pues eso, estoy tratando de filtrar los duplicados de una tabla con grocery y parece que ignora por completo mi consulta, he probado con `distinct()`, `group by()` e incluso ambas al mismo tiempo.

Lo que quiero es mostrar la tabla sin duplicados.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

**Controller**

```
 $this->Fechacita_Model->delete_duplicaterow();
```

**Model**

```
public function delete_duplicaterow() {
     $this->db->select('c.intervaloHorario', 'ci.cita');
     $this->db->distinct();
     $this->db->from('intervaloshorarios c');
     $this->db->join('citas ci', 'c.idIntervaloHorario = ci.idIntervaloHorario', 'right');
     $this->db->group_by('c.intervaloHorario','ci.cita');
     $query = $this->db->get();

     return $query->num_rows();
}
```

**DB**

[image: Relacion 1:1]

**Captura**
[image: tabla]

Comment: Tenes forma de ver el query que se envía a la base de datos?

Comment: Viendo tu esquema hay algo que me llama la atención. Tienes una relación 1:1 y el intervaloHorario como varchar, es posible que intervaloHorario no sea exactamente igual en los 2 registros? Que tenga algún espacio o algo de más alguno de los campos. Por otro lado veo más bien una relación 1:N, un intervalo muchas citas

Comment: Así es como estaba antes, un intervalo muchas citas pero ya a la desesperada lo cambié para ver si la consulta iba... Y tampoco, un intervalo va como string y el otro es la clave primaria de la tabla... A ver si podéis echarme una mano

Comment: Respondiendo a @Juan intentaré ver la consulta completa a ver